# Value change while data transfer via TCP

Tags: c++, qt, tcp

I have a TCP-server and a TCP-client written in c++ using QTcp-Classes. Now I have the problem that sometimes the server emits a `0`, but the client receives a `1`. As soon as this problem emerges, I have to restart everything for correcting this bug.
The lowest-level-functions responsible for telling me the data are:

*Client*:

```
void Client::readData()
{
    QDataStream in(tcpSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
    if (blockSize == 0) {
        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
            return;

        in >> blockSize;
    }
    if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
    {
        qDebug() << tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() << ' ' << blockSize;
        return;
    }
    in >> data;
    blockSize = 0;
    //qDebug() << "Client got new data!";
    qDebug() << data.first << " " << data.second.toInt();
    emit Client::gotData(data);

}
```

*Server*:

```
void Server::sendData(QPair<QString, QVariant> data)
{
//! [5]
    //QString data = "";
    QPair<QString, QVariant> send_data = data;
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
    out << (quint16)0;
    out << send_data;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    if(Server::clientConnection != NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << "New Connection: " << Server::clientConnection->peerAddress().toString() << " on Port: " << Server::clientConnection->peerPort();
        QVariant ipAddr_QVar(Server::clientConnection->peerAddress().toString());
        qDebug() << "New qvariant: " << ipAddr_QVar;

        clientConnection->write(block);
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "No connection!";
}
```

Every variable which is not defined within the functions above is defined in the corresponding class.
The `sendData()`-function is called via (Signal-Slot-mechanism):

```
void controller::positionChanged()
{
    QVariant tmp(0);
    qDebug() << "Position changed, stepper stopped " << tmp.toString() << "!";
    emit sendDataMain(qMakePair(QString("STP"), tmp));
}
```

The positionChanged()-qDebug()-function prints me a `0`, but sometimes the readData-function prints me a `1`.
What I did till now:
I tried to look into the tcp-data with wireshark, but I can not read QDataStreams...
I tried it with a debugger, but then the same situation arises, and the debugger tells me the same as `qDebug()`. So, currently I have no idea what I did wrong, and maybe someone here can help me?

Comment: Is the issue is solved? can you expand `clientConnection->write(block);`

Comment: What do you mean with "expand `clientConnection->write(block);`? `clientConnection` is a `QTcpSocket`, and `write()` is a function of this class.

Comment: `if (clientConnection->waitForBytesWritten(5000))
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "sent";
    }`

add this after write.